# Generation ship. People live in separate villages. Not allowed to intermarry. Society based on South or Central America before Europeans came

Tags: story-identification, novel

The story starts with everyone witnessing a priest digging a sharp instrument into a young girl's brain and killing her. The priest says she is free now. Our young male protagonist thinks to himself, she is dead also.

The plan of the people who designed the society was not to allow people from different villages to interbreed during the journey. All the offspring would not be too intelligent and be unlikely to cause too much trouble in flight. Their plan was that after finding an inhabitable planet to settle, the different villages could then interbreed to produce far more intelligent and adventurous people. These planned smart people were called the Arrivers. They modelled the on board society on historic South or Central America as these were very stable societies. Their mistake was that they made the society too stable.

Our young hero was born as a result of an illegal affair. His parents were from different villages, so he is the first Arriver and very smart.

He climbs up inside the spaceship one day and touches the sky, maybe the sun too. I think this was depicted on the cover.

He finds out that they did arrive at a solar system some years ago. The people in charge decided the planets were unsuitable as they were much smaller than the star and glowed only from reflected light, not producing their own.

I think he eventually got them to turn back to properly investigate these planets and to change the laws so many more smart Arrivers would be born.

I read it in the 80s or 90s. It felt like it was written earlier. I borrowed it from a library in the UK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is *Captive Universe* by Harry Harrison.

This review is from the [British Interplanetary Society](https://bis-space.com/membership/jbis/2018/JBIS-v71-no02-February-2018-kf92bx.pdf)

> A notable example from science fiction is [Harry
> Harrison's *Captive Universe*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_Universe) in which Aztec tribes (the “Arrivers”) are unknowing passengers aboard a worldship maintained by a religious overseer culture (comprised of “Watchmen” and “Observers”). Predictably, the religious-like devotion
> of the “Observers” is also their downfall, as it causes them to
> fail entirely to identify potential destinations. They have come
> to believe that they must find a world like the one the “Arrivers”
> inhabit aboard ship, with an artificial “sun” that transits around
> the “valley” where the Arrivers live. Consequently, they judge
> the strange arrangements they keep finding – planets orbiting
> around stars – as unsuitable!
>
> [image]

Comment: I will check it out, thanks.

Comment: Yes, this is it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Wow, that sounds like quite the read. Going to grab that myself.